# how to refresh an oauth token when using the Facebook iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook, oauth, ios

I'm using the Facebook SDK for iOS in my app:  http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

The oAuth token expires after about 2 hours.  How can I "refresh" the oAuth token without having  to call the [Facebook authorize...] method again - which shows an empty Facebook dialog briefly if the user had previously logged in?    What I want to avoid is requiring the user to re-login to FB each time they use the app - say, day to day.

I am already saving / restoring oAuth tokens when the app exits / starts.  And I can check to see if the token is valid using [Facebook isSessionValid], or by checking the expire time on the token.  But what to do if the token has expired?  I've read that it is possible to "refresh" the token, but I don't understand how this is done.

I don't want to request "offline_access" permission, which would give me a "forever" token.

Help!?

Comment: Were you abel to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook's implementation of OAuth doesn't support token refresh.

You have 2 types of access_tokens in Facebook. Short term token, which is given by default and a long term token which is given if you request offline_access. If refresh token were supported, it was the same as giving a offline_access token for all apps.

As long as the user has an active facebook session on your web control, you can request a new access_token just by accessing https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token or probably some iOS SDK command that does the same (never worked with it so I can't tell). This kind of request will not ask the user to login again, but will use the previous session that was created during the first login.

Answer (score 3):

Since none of these answers actually addressed the question I am going to detail how I have implemented OAuth token refresh using The Facebook SDK.

The SDK will automatically refresh your tokens when you make requests however, in my scenario we send the tokens to our servers and we need to use the latest token. So when our server indicates that we need new tokens this is what we do:

**Note** You can either pass the AppID into the `FBSession` or you can add the `FacebookAppID` key to your App's plist (this is what we do).

```
- (void)renewFacebookCredentials {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen ||
        FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:[FBSession activeSession] state:[FBSession activeSession].state error:nil];
    } else {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email"]
                                           allowLoginUI:NO
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          //this block will run throughout the lifetime of the app.
                                          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                      }];
    }
}
```

The you can use the `sessionStateChanged:` method that Facebook include in their documentation but a simplified handler looks like this:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
    // If the session was opened successfully
    NSString *accessToken;
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen && [[session accessTokenData] accessToken]){
        // Show the user the logged-in UI

        //@see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623728/getting-username-and-profile-picture-from-facebook-ios-7
        accessToken = [[session accessTokenData] accessToken];
       //Now we have an access token, can send this to the server...
    } else {
       //No access token, show a dialog or something
    }

   //either call a delegate or a completion handler here with the accessToken
}
```

Be aware that some of the FBSession API calls check for thread affinity so I found that I had to wrap all my FBSession calls inside a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...`

Answer (score 0):

Just do [ [FBSession session] resume] if it return false do login again

Comment: this is what I used to do.  the latest FB SDK on github removed the FBSession object, and I see no "resume" method anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook iOS SDK doesn’t handle the session storage. 
FBSessionDelegate is a callback interface that your application should implement. it's methods will be invoked on application's successful login or logout.

See the example application `facebook-ios-sdk/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m` for `fbDidLogin`, `fbDidNotLogin` and `fbDidLogout` methods

Answer (score 0):

As per the Facebook SDK documentation:

> The Facebook SDK automatically refreshes the user's session if
> necessary. When it does this, the state also transitions to the
> `FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended` state.

Also to further clarify (since SDK version 3.1):

> The SDK refreshes session automatically on API calls.
>
> It also refreshes the token data as needed when follow-on authentication or Facebook API calls made using the SDK.

Comment: Yep; my question is a few years old now.  The FBSDK has evolved quite a lot since then!

Comment: Was searching for this answer and this SO thread came up, so I summed up what I researched myself.

Answer (score 0):

As of today Facebook is supposed to refresh tokens automatically, requests to GraphAPI can be done without providing token string either (Facebook handles it under the hood).

Moreover, if it happens that user wasn't using app for a long time and his token managed to expire, on your next request to Graph API an alert will be shown by Facebook's SDK asking user to relogin (all that is handled by Facebook and when done - will return into `FBSDKGraphRequest`'s closure).

[image]

However, if someone really has a reason to manually refresh access token, here's an example (Swift 4):

```
private var selfDestructableNotificationToken: NotificationTokenThatAutomaticallyRemovesObserver?
final class NotificationTokenThatAutomaticallyRemovesObserver: NSObject { // more info here: https://oleb.net/blog/2018/01/notificationcenter-removeobserver/
    let token: Any
    init(_ token: Any) { self.token = token }
    deinit { NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token) }
}

...

if let currentFBToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current() { // if this is a Facebook user, not an email-based user
    if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessTokenIsActive() { // and his token has not expired yet
        let token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.FBSDKAccessTokenDidChange, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { notification in
            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo, let refreshedToken = userInfo["FBSDKAccessToken"] as? FBSDKAccessToken {
                self.fbAccessToken = refreshedToken.tokenString
            } else {
                self.fbAccessToken = currentFBToken.tokenString // falling back to using an old token (better than none)
            }
        }
        self.selfDestructableNotificationToken = NotificationTokenThatAutomaticallyRemovesObserver(token)
        FBSDKAccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessToken { _, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to refresh Facebook token with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                self.fbAccessToken = currentFBToken.tokenString // falling back to an old token (better than none)
            }
        }
    } else if FBSDKAccessToken.current().isExpired { // unlucky user. Probably returned to the app after > 2 months break
        self.fbAccessToken = currentFBToken.tokenString // assigning expired token. Facebook will ask user to relogin as soon as we call Graph API with that expired token
    }
}
```