# Facebook iOS SDK: refreshing an expired access token without presenting a dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, oauth

I'm using the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). In my code I have authorized my app with the default permissions, so my session is valid until the expiration date is reached. However, after the expiration date is reached, I attempt to reauthorize in order to "refresh my OAuth token", as [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610682/how-to-refresh-an-oauth-token-when-using-the-facebook-iphone-sdk).

However, when I attempt to reauthorize, it displays a dialog saying I have already authorized my app, even though I expect it to just update my OAuth token without a dialog. According to facebook, [this is possible](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/):

> When you redirect the user to the auth dialog, the user is not
>   prompted for permissions if the user has already authorized your
>   application. **Facebook will return you a valid access token without any
>   user facing dialog**.

However, I do get a dialog and I'd like to know how I can refresh the access token **without** getting the dialog.

Comment: I believe that the behavior Facebook describes in the post you linked to only works for web apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recent [commit](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/4aa2a663b2b735cc736b4177a1947e176d9f4446) in the Facebook iOS SDK project included an "extend access token" method for extending an expired token.

More information about this and the deprecation of "offline_access" is in Facebook Developer's [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/).

Comment: This extends access token api doesn't seem to work for me at all

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around is to request offline_access as a permission. Then the access token only expires when:

The user logs out of facebook
Changes their password
Revokes permissions for your app via the facebook website

If anyone has a better answer id like to know too. Requesting offline access for my app could look a bit suspicious (even though the only reason I need it is for non-expiring access token, I wont actually be accessing a users account when their not using my app).

Comment: offline_access is now deprecated, unfortunately.