# Handling expired access tokens in iOS app

Tags: ios, access-token, facebook-oauth

What are the best practices when it comes to handling expired access tokens in an iOS app? 
For example, the user could change their Facebook password, or they could simply remove the FB app from their profile. Or maybe they could forget about the app for 60 days and then start reusing it. In all cases the access token would be invalid, so the app would have to get a fresh one with an `authorize` call (which would open the Facebook app for a second and then go back to the app with the access token).

Is there any way to get a fresh access token inside an iOS app without having to re-authorize? I went through a few [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373383/facebook-ios-sdk-refreshing-an-expired-access-token-without-presenting-a-dialog) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610682/how-to-refresh-an-oauth-token-when-using-the-facebook-iphone-sdk) I found here about this, but still haven't found a way.

What exactly should the app do in this case? Maybe it could present a dialog asking the user to authorize again if they want the app to keep interacting with Facebook? I think that would be pretty annoying, but I can't see any other solutions. Any ideas? What are other apps doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to ask the user to authorize the app again.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @jesse : How can we find, whether the access token valid or invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from Facebook docs, error responses and how to react with a PHP example:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: Hi Billy, just checked and the link is still active / directs me to the proper page.